# How to remove a specific number from file with bash

Tags: bash, centos

I have a directory full of .gif files and for some reason after I did a migration from an old server, all of them now have 1 on them. So instead of being profilepic123_ its profilepic123_1. I need to remove the 1 from the file name. This directory has around 300+ images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rename _1 _ *.gif
```

or whatever file extensions you have in your directory.

This assumes that there is only one instance of `_1` in your filenames. Something like `profilepic123_123_1.gif` will break.